# I have a question regarding Jmeter thread group section

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter Thread group section, if I am adding 3000 threads with a ramp-up time of 15000 secs, does that mean all 3000 users will be active till 15000 secs ends?

How many simultaneous users are on my website in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Every 5 seconds a thread will be created until end of 15000 secs.

Simultaneous users depends on test plan execution, if only 1 loop and 1 request that finished in less than 5 seconds then you will have only 1 simultaneous user.

If loop is inifinite you will have 3000 simultaneous users after 15000 secs

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends

- on the number of iterations you define in the Thread Group
- number of Samplers
- your application response time

1. Your "3000 threads with a ramp up time of 15000 secs" configuration means that JMeter starts a new thread (virtual user) each 5 seconds.
2. Once started thread starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
3. When there are no more Samplers to execute and loops to iterate - the sampler gets shut down

So depending on the number of loops and response time you can have from 0 to 3000 users.

In order to check the actual concurrency you can use i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](http://3000%20threads%20with%20a%20ramp%20up%20time%20of%2015000%20secs) and [Server Hits Per Second plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) (they can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Time taken per user to activate = Ramp up time / No. of threads, in your case 15000/3000 = 5 sec per user.

as you can see 1 user will be added per 5 second and eventually you will have all 3000 users active by the end of 15000 sec, given your first or any other user does not complete iteration and shut itself before last user gets chance to start ( last user starts at 15000th sec here)

Note : To achieve a load of 3000 users by the end of 15000sec, you can set LoopCount to "infinite" but this will cause increase in number of total samplers and you may end up iterating your script way more than 3000 times.